# After page load bootstrap always changes position of elements with absolute position on phones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Concrete problem is that I want have a page on server with structure of elements with nice positioning, but I couldn´t get it into desired shape, but only with setting them absolute position counted by screen resolution on mobile phones with jquery. After page load bootstrap will move my elements with absolute path more up. All those elements are at the bottom of page. I know that it is bootstrap, because when I will not add bootstrap server links, everything is fine as far as position of my elements is concerned. But naturally I need bootstrap there.

I tried to figure it out in many ways, but I ended with tryings to wait with jquery till the page load and after that try to set position. But no, after all moving in function that is called after page load, bootstrap starts doing it´s job later as last and don´t know how and why, but it trim my elements and push all my circles all up with bad height positions.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
// script for setting bubble circles in right place on whatever screen
// this is updated question for correct answer below, id=allCircles is id of global div for circles
$width = $('#allCircles').width();
$circleWidth = parseInt($('.circle').css('width'),10);
$circlesDistance = 60;
$leftCircles = ($width)/2 -(($circlesDistance/2)+$circleWidth);
$rightCircles = ($width)/2 + ($circlesDistance/2);

$('.left-circle').css('left', $leftCircles+'px' );
$('.right-circle').css('left', $rightCircles +'px');

$actPosition = $("#leftDownCircle").position();
$heightMargin= $actPosition.top + $circleWidth/2;

$('#leftDownCircle').css('top', $heightMargin+'px' );
$('#rightDownCircle').css('top', $heightMargin+'px' );

$leftMargin = ($width)/2 - ($circleWidth/2);
$heightMargin = ($heightMargin) -($circleWidth/2)-($circleWidth/4);

$('#middleCircle').css('position','absolute');
$('#middleCircle').css('left', $leftMargin +'px' );
$('#middleCircle').css('top', $heightMargin +'px' );

});
```

```css
* {margin:0;}
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgrey;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  line-height: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.left-circle {
    position: absolute; left: 15%;
}
.right-circle {
    position: absolute; left: 60%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>



</head>


<body>


<div class="left-circle">
  <div class="circle">
    <h1>9</h1>
    <p>Level</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right-circle">
  <div class="circle">
    <h1>9</h1>
    <p>Level</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="middleCircle">
  <div class="circle">
    <h1>9</h1>
    <p>Level</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="left-circle" id="leftDownCircle">
  <div class="circle">
    <h1>9</h1>
    <p>Level</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right-circle" id="rightDownCircle">
  <div class="circle" >
    <h1>9</h1>
    <p>Level</p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

When I will add in this code to html header this:

```
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Then on phone it will result to this:

[image: example]
[image: example2]

Could someone help me to answer how this can be done programmatically correctly? (maybe why this not work or what is better practice to make the desired result as in snippet, thanks in advance for any help and your time!)

> Now concrete site whith its code in it. Web emulator looks:
>
> http://mobiletest.me/htc_one_emulator/?u=https://stackoverflowtest.000webhostapp.com/
>
> Concrete site to test with your mobile device:
>
> https://stackoverflowtest.000webhostapp.com/

Notice left-down waiting for bootstrap and after reload:
[image]

Comment: The code you are adding into the header has an unclosed opening script tag:   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:    </script>

Comment: Thanks Leo for noticing this mistake, but thats only mistake made when I was making a snippet from my code, I checked it in my files and have this script link correct... problem lays in sth other.. but I found out that in some iphones it work correct, but not in my android device...but web emulator shows that it should not work for iphone, I will update my question with that result + correct that snippet...

Comment: It would be nice for person that downvoted this question to at least comment why is it bad question... I´ve spent many many hours by searching for faults and gave here all the code for this problem, and I found no similar problems in s.o. ... if you will just downvote and not explain it, you should better not wonder why are people asking bad questions... for example type: "bad code practices..." .. but I have already read all tutorials for making good questions...

Comment: hmmm... I tried out your code in an iphone simulator and it looked okay. Is it possible some other code your haven't posted is causing the problem? Do you see any errors in your browser console?

Comment: No errors, no warnings... 200 OK 352ms with firebug... OK! I made another account for webhosting just for stackoverflow... I will update link to site that you can test on mobile from your home...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem you are having is that by making the elements absolute, they are positioned in relation to the nearest non-static parent element. I don't see any non-static parent elements on your page, so in your case they will be positioned relative to the `body`. This causes a problem as you have lots of other elements that can be different sizes (e.g. because of text wrapping over multiple lines on mobile screen that would only take one line on desktop size) before you get to the circles so determining the right `top` value in relation to `body` is not possible.

Note, two of your circles don't have a `top` value set, so they are placed in their default static places, which is why you are getting the overlaps.

To fix it, you need to place a non-static element around your absolute elements (e.g. by giving it a `position:relative` style). Position `top` and `left` values the circles in relation to that element and give the element a height that will give the circles enough space.

e.g.

```
 <div style="min-height: 550px;position:relative;">
    <div class="left-circle" style="left: 30px;">
        <div class="circle">
            <h2>345</h2>
            <p>Bodov</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-circle" style="left: 190px;">
        <div class="circle">
            <h2>11</h2>
            <p>Best of</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="middleCircle" style="position: absolute;
        left: 110px;
        top: 100px;">
        <div class="circle">
            <h1>9</h1>
            <p>Uroven</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="left-circle" id="leftDownCircle" style="left: 30px;
    top: 198px;">
        <div class="circle">
            <h2>1622</h2>
            <p>Zaradenych knih</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-circle" id="rightDownCircle" style="left: 190px;
    top: 198px;">
        <div class="circle">
            <h2>124</h2>
            <p>Citatelov</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The key things to note here are:

1. I have put all your circles inside a div with a `position:relative` and a `height:550px;`
2. I have changed the top values of the circles to position themselves in relation to this new parent div.

Comment: well.. packaging all in div with position relative resloved my problem.. thanks... but I don't understand why you set it height:550px and I don't understand why you wrote those styles for circles when styles are made with jquery script... well, the only thing that made it correct was to pack it to div and set position:relative... thanks for your explanation, I know understand that absolute/relative parenting...

Comment: As far as the height goes. If your relative element has only absolute children, it effectively has no height. So, to reserve the space on the page that the absolute elements need, what I usually do is to work out how much height those element need and to assign that height to the parent (this ensures other elements on the page don't overlap your absolute elements). In your case, I think you had achieved the same thing by giving an element below a large margin. That's fine too. I'm just giving a heads-up that space should be reserved and the way I've shown is the most common way.

Comment: With the styles for the circles, that was just to show you how the heights should change to work inside a relative element. You are right that they can be set using your javascript.